# See Firebase network traffic in debug purpose

Tags: analytics, firebase-analytics, network-traffic

I want to be able to debug the firebase analytics using Charles Proxy. I don't have access to the source code and can therefore not enable the debug view in Firebase.

I want to track the network traffic to be able to see what events that is sent within my app using Charles proxy for Firebase Analytics data. I have tried to set up an SSL connection using Charles proxy but can't see the Firebase Analytics traffic from my app.

The purpose of this is since I don't have access to source code in the app and can't thereby enable debugView.

I want to be able to see the network traffic from my app that is sent to Firebase Analytics. The same principal as you can do for Google Analytics data.

Comment: Have you managed to find out this?

Comment: No, I need to check XCode or Android studio to see what is sent.