# How can sniff Firebase Events?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using **Charles Proxy** as Sniffer to check and verify the body/payload of my **Firebase Events**?

I see the POST request to firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog in Batch, and in each event, inside the POST request, I found the sourceExtension attrib, that I think constains all the event data, but I cant to decode, I tryed with base64 and bytes, but I cant see the content of the property.

I know the documented way to check firebase events is thourght the web portal in debug view, but this question is about how to see the content in the request before it arrive to the google cloud.

[image: Image from Chales Proxy desktop app in windows]

I saw another related post in Stackoverflow, but without any answers:
[See Firebase network traffic in debug purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56053703/see-firebase-network-traffic-in-debug-purpose)

Anyone know how to sniff Firebase events and decode correctly? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`sourceExtension` seem to be a Protobuf of the event. The library Google uses for the API transport is open source on Github if you want to continue digging for more details and exactly how to decode it. Some links:

- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/transport/transport-backend-cct/src/main/java/com/google/android/datatransport/cct/internal/LogEvent.java
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/9b48edd65856a866f752412e017f52546867c743/transport/transport-backend-cct/src/main/java/com/google/android/datatransport/cct/CctTransportBackend.java#L255-L264
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/transport/transport-runtime/src/main/java/com/google/android/datatransport/runtime/EncodedPayload.java
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/9b48edd65856a866f752412e017f52546867c743/firebase-inappmessaging/src/proto/firebase/inappmessaging/proto/common_types.proto#L53

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).